# How do you read ARRAY column from Parquet file in stage?

Tags: parquet, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Parquet files with ARRAY data type in an external stage. I can query the columns with $1:::datatype syntax but I'm having trouble figuring out how to query the column that is ARRAY data type.

Querying it without casting shows the value as this: { "list": [ { "element": "1" }, { "element": "4" } ] }

But what I'm expecting is the array: ["1", "4"]

I've tried casting to array or variant but it's just wrapping the value in [] instead of what I want. I can probably get it to how I want using flatten, array_construct, and such but is there a simpler way to get an ARRAY from Parquet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parquet file support in Snowflake appears to use this form of structured output for list/array datatypes encountered in the file schema.

While there appears to be no way to influence it [via options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#type-parquet), the real data carried within the produced structure is intact, so you can perform a [transformation via UDF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/user-defined-functions.html) to get your stripped array of primitives:

```sql
create or replace function PARQ_LIST_TO_ARRAY(PARQ_LIST VARIANT)
    returns ARRAY
    language javascript
    as
    '
        values = []
        PARQ_LIST.list.forEach( (e) => {
            values.push(e.element)
        })
        return values
    ';
```

You can also run this over a Parquet file column directly (such as [during load](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html)):

```sql
> select $1:arr_col_name as lst from @stage/file.parquet;
lst
{ "list": [ { "element": "1" }, { "element": "4" } ] }

> select PARQ_LIST_TO_ARRAY($1:arr_col_name) as arr from @stage/file.parquet;
arr
["1", "4"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems silly we have to do this to get array